# Routing only VM traffic through VPN

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, vpn

I'm stuck on a problem and would like some help if possible :-)
My goal is to make my VM going through my VPN connection and my HOST through the standard gateway.

Configuration :
VM (192.168.100.1) => HOST-TAP0 (192.168.100.254) => VPN-TUN0 (10.8.0.62) => VPN-TUNX (10.8.0.61)

Here is my iptables configuration :

```
# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tap0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    3   297 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5  1491 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2   144 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.19.255      
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            255.255.255.255     
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.1           
    1    32 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:138 dpt:138
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "INPUT-DROP "
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tap0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tap0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "FORWARD-DROP "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 277 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         


# iptables -L -n -v -tnat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 66 packets, 9746 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 330 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 330 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.100.1        0.0.0.0/0           


# iptables -L -n -v -tmangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 305 packets, 48293 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   183 MARK       all  --  *      *       192.168.100.1       !192.168.0.0/16       MARK set 0x33

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 297 packets, 47445 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 183 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 235 packets, 24805 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 238 packets, 24988 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Here is my ip rule :

```
# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local 
32764:  from all fwmark 0x33 lookup ks 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And my ip route :

```
# ip route 
default via 192.168.19.254 dev eno1  metric 202 
10.8.0.0/16 dev tun0  scope link 
10.8.0.61 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.62 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope host 
127.0.0.0/8 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo 
169.254.0.0/16 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.55.59  metric 204 
192.168.19.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.19.126  metric 202 
192.168.100.0/24 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.254 


# ip route show table ks
default via 10.8.0.61 dev tun0 
10.8.0.0/16 dev tun0  scope link 
192.168.100.0/24 dev tap0  scope link
```

ip_forward is activated :

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

conntrack compiled with the kernel :

```
# grep -i conntrack .config
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK is not set
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROCFS=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMEOUT is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMESTAMP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_AMANDA is not set
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_H323 is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IRC is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_NETBIOS_NS is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SNMP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SANE is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SIP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROC_COMPAT=y
```

tcpdump on tap0 (connected to the VM) :

```
# tcpdump -n -i tap0 host 216.58.208.206
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

18:23:13.295621 IP 192.168.100.1.1165 > 216.58.208.206.80: Flags [S], seq 1720703916, win 16384, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
18:23:16.188006 IP 192.168.100.1.1165 > 216.58.208.206.80: Flags [S], seq 1720703916, win 16384, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

and tcpdump on tun0 (the VPN interface) :

```
# tcpdump -n -i tun0 host 216.58.208.206
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
18:24:02.943753 IP 10.8.0.62.1166 > 216.58.208.206.80: Flags [S], seq 2743155711, win 16384, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
18:24:02.957965 IP 216.58.208.206.80 > 10.8.0.62.1166: Flags [S.], seq 1382398319, ack 2743155712, win 42900, options [mss 1368,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
18:24:03.433187 IP 216.58.208.206.80 > 10.8.0.62.1166: Flags [S.], seq 1382398319, ack 2743155712, win 42900, options [mss 1368,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
18:24:05.438445 IP 216.58.208.206.80 > 10.8.0.62.1166: Flags [S.], seq 1382398319, ack 2743155712, win 42900, options [mss 1368,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

It seems that I miss something as the traffic seems to go through the VPN, return back but is not forwarded to the tap0 for the virtual machine.

Any help ?
Thank you a lot !
Nelson

Comment: You shouldn't need the `fwmark` stuff nor even **any** iptables involvement to get this done. `ip rule from 192.168.0.1/32 lookup ks` should be all you need.

Comment: Thank you Celada, that's a perfect solution.
Any idea on what is making my method failing ?