# Network routing through veth0 / bridge for userspace QEMU VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, bridge, tap, veth

I would like to filter and capture traffic from a virtual machine.  This VM must run in userspace.  Capturing requires root, I know (though I hope to minimise root activity needed later).

The easiest way to capture and filter - as I understand - is having a dedicated, virtual network interface like `vnet0` used exclusively by the VM.  Then I can run `tshark`, `tcpdump`, `iptables` etc. on it.

**How do I set up (create) the network interfaces (as root), and how do I connect to them (as non-root) with a KVM/QEMU virtual machine?**

I am looking for `ip` commands (iproute2 style) and qemu configuration options.

I have started working on interfaces like this:

```
(root 1) ip link add br0 type bridge
(root 2) ip addr add dev br0 10.10.0.1/24
(root 3) ip link set dev br0 up
(root 4) ip link add vm1-host type veth peer name vm1-net
(root 5) ip link set dev vm1-host master br0
(root 6) ip link set dev vm1-host up
(root 7) ip tuntap add vm1-tap mode tap
(root 8) ip addr add 10.10.0.2/24 dev vm1-net
(root 9) ip addr add 10.0.2.2/24 dev vm1-tap
(root 10) ip link set dev vm1-tap up
(root 10b) echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then tried to connect with QEMU to the bridge but could not do so as a non-root user.

I edited `/etc/qemu/bridge.conf` to allow the user to connect to the bridge via /usr/libexec`/qemu-bridge-helper`:

```
(root 11) grep -v # /etc/qemu/bridge.conf
allow veth0
allow vm1-tap
allow vm1-host
allow vm1-net
(root 12) ll /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper 
-rwsr-x--- 1 root kvm 312888 Aug 25 16:16 /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper
```

The user is indeed a member of the `kvm` group (`id` shows it). However, I get the following error message when using`virt-manager` running as `$USERNAME` with a bridge interface:

```
Error starting domain: /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper --use-vnet --br=vm1-tap --fd=34: failed to communicate with bridge helper: stderr=failed to add interface `tap0' to bridge `vm1-tap': Operation not supported
: Transport endpoint is not connected

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1425, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1362, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: /usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper --use-vnet --br=vm1-tap --fd=34: failed to communicate with bridge helper: stderr=failed to add interface `tap0' to bridge `vm1-tap': Operation not supported
: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Some **capabilities** may additionally be necessary? - **how do I make a user have them only for starting the VM?**

Perhaps this will help?

```
(root 13) ip tuntap add vm1-tap mode tap user $USERNAME
ioctl(TUNSETIFF): Device or resource busy
```

I experimented with commands found online but **do I need tun/tap at all?**, and I could not find the correct way to do this.

References (helpful but not solutions for my problem):

- [Howto setup a `veth` virtual network](https://superuser.com/questions/764986/howto-setup-a-veth-virtual-network)
- [QEMU - network bridge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456449/qemu-network-bridge)
- [Routing only VM traffic through VPN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219952/routing-only-vm-traffic-through-vpn)

Comment: Are you intending to route or to bridge this VM? So far I don't see the role of having a bridge around nor the role of the vm1-host/vm1-net veth pair where both sides are kept on the same network namespace. They all appear superfluous, unless I missed something. Also, if you have already dome some tests with qemu, you should provide where you got so far, including a qemu command + args.

Comment: @don_aman `/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper` is `-rwsr-x--- 1 root kvm` so indeed SUID 0 but apparently that does not suffice.

Comment: @A.B My understanding is that any dedicated network device would be ideal. Yes if routed/NATed is easier please do suggest something and I will try it out! I do not need a device with a separate MAC address in the network (which only the bridging approach would provide IIUC).  Will provide the `qemu` command later, used `virt-manager` so I need to extract it.

Comment: Anyway, irrelevant to the layout you should try this: `ip tuntap add vm1-tap mode tap user FOO` with FOO the user running qemu.

Comment: https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/ has more information. Basically with your way of configuring things (persistent interface), qemu-bridge-helper is not needed. It's really needed for transient interfaces (and also for the bridge part, but you handle it before).

Comment: About the last edit: trying to set an interface as bridge port of a non-bridge interface is an Operation not supported. It's not about credentials. qemu-bridge-helper is anyway not useful at all here and that will be my last comment.

Comment: @don_aman The `qemu-system` command is not visible within `virt-manager` because apparently the `qemu-bridge-helper` command is generated and executed first - and fails.

Comment: @A.B Thanks. Kindly indicate what to do instead of using `qemu-bridge-helper` - which QEMU network config to use instead of a bridge I suppose?  `macvtap`??

Comment: I got no reply about my `user FOO` comment.

Comment: @A.B Please check the (root 13) commandline, I hope that was typed correctly.

Comment: Yes, that should be `root 7`

Comment: @A.B OK thanks I will try it in that order. I assume it may not be UP for the user command to work. Will try that and edit the question on the weekend.

Comment: And my very first comment wrote "Also, if you have already dome some tests with qemu, you should provide where you got so far, including a qemu command + args.". But now I can read "Error starting domain:" which suggests it's done through libvirtd. This should be stated. Probably changes a lot (because usually there's nothing special to do with a libvirt installation). Or if I'm mistaken, providing a reproducible command would help.

Comment: @A.B The "Error starting domain" is from `virt-manager` running as `$USERNAME`. Will try to do my QEMU homework on the weekend.

Comment: well the output is clear, libvirt is adding a tap device to a bridge, but the specified bridge is actually not a bridge, at least not according to your iproute2 network setup command `ip tuntap add vm1-tap mode tap`. shouldn't `vm1-tap` be a bridge? or more likely you should change the configured bridge to `br0`

Comment: You can filter with iptables and capture with iptables NFLOG+tcpdump. Why do you need all interface routing blackmagic?

Comment: @gapsf I need to connect (and ideally, also run ipfilter) as non-root. If you have a different way please compose an Answer.

Comment: @A.B Please write an answer, you seem to know the solution. I did not manage to find out by myself. Here is a bounty.

Comment: My last comment was ~ 9 months ago. And no I don't know the solution, because I was asking for a reproducible setup with a qemu command, and then discovered it was using libvirt (which wasn't told). And when using libvirt one can't really customize outside of it.

Comment: @A.B OK, thanks anyway.